# Question If my argument needs proof

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

In my assignment, I have to use the following:
$$ \Big \lfloor \sqrt{n^2-1} \Big \rfloor=\Big \lfloor \sqrt{n^2} \Big \rfloor -1$$
Can I use it without proof or do I have to proove it?

Comment: Is $n$ an integer? If not, there are plenty of counterexamples.

Comment: If it's given to you without further explanation, then no you don't need to prove it. Maths questions are (or ought to be) very specific in their formulation; if they want you to prove it, they should say so.

Comment: I agree with @H.sapiensrex.  If needed, $~n^2 > n^2 - 1 > n^2 - 2n + 1 = (n-1)^2. ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$